# Segmentation Fault occurring for no obvious reason

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting the segmentation fault for no obvious reason. I am using the `strtok` function and splitting each line into multiple tokens and storing them in char pointers. My data looks like this:

Input:

```
200 -> 103 [weight=7];
200 -> 153 [weight=27];
200 -> 53 [weight=9];
200 -> 178 [weight=43];
55 -> 2 [weight=23];
55 -> 14 [weight=50];
55 -> 20 [weight=17];
55 -> 22 [weight=1];
55 -> 74 [weight=7];
55 -> 93 [weight=9];
55 -> 122 [weight=27];
65 -> 8 [weight=27];
65 -> 9 [weight=9];
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        char *ipfile,line[80];
        FILE *fp;
        char *field1,*field2,*field3,*field4,*field5,*field6,mystr[10];
        int row,column,weight;
        ipfile = (char *)argv[1];
        printf("The input file name is %s\n",ipfile);
        fp = fopen(ipfile,"r");

        if(fp ==NULL) //Checking whether the command line argument was correctly or not.
        printf("There is no such file in the directory.\n");

        while(fgets(line,80,fp) != NULL)
        {
                field1 = strtok(line," ");
                //row    = atoi(field1);
                field2 = strtok(NULL," ");
                field3 = strtok(NULL," ");
                //column = atoi(field3);
                field4 = strtok(NULL," ");
                field5 = strtok(NULL," ");
                //field6 = strtok(NULL," ");

                printf("%s\n",field5);
                //printf("Row-%d Column - %d Weight - %d\n",row,column,weight);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

From a comment:

> When I try printing `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4` they are getting printed. But when I try `field5` and `field6` my program is giving a segmentation fault.

Adding code after SO user's suggestion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        char *ipfile,line[80];
        FILE *fp;
        char *field1,*field2,*field3,*field4,*field5,*field6,mystr[10];
        int row,column,weight;
        ipfile = (char *)argv[1];
        printf("The input file name is %s\n",ipfile);
        fp = fopen(ipfile,"r");

        if(fp == NULL) //Checking whether the command line argument was correctly or not.
        printf("There is no such file in the directory.\n");

        while(fgets(line,80,fp) != NULL)
        {
                field1 = strtok(line," ");
                //row    = atoi(field1);
                field2 = strtok(NULL," ");
                field3 = strtok(NULL," ");
                //column = atoi(field3);
                field4 = strtok(NULL," ");
                field5 = strtok(NULL," []=;");
                //field6 = strtok(NULL," ");

                printf("%s\n",field5);
                //printf("Row-%d Column - %d Weight - %d\n",row,column,weight);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is always a reason.

Comment: When I try printing field1,field2,field3,field4 they are getting printed.But when I try field5 and field6 my program is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: Exhibit the input that is generating the error.

Comment: Note that even though you report a problem if the file doesn't open, you go ahead and use the null file pointer anyway.  It's a good idea to exit or return after spotting such an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char line[80];
    char *field1, *field2, *field3, *field4, *field5;
    char *ipfile = argv[1];

    if (argc == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }
    printf("The input file name is %s\n", ipfile);
    FILE *fp = fopen(ipfile, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) //Checking whether the command line argument was correctly or not.
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "There is no such file in the directory.\n");
        return(1);
    }

    char const *delim = " [];=";
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Input: %s", line);
        field1 = strtok(line, delim);
        //row    = atoi(field1);
        field2 = strtok(NULL, delim);
        field3 = strtok(NULL, delim);
        //column = atoi(field3);
        field4 = strtok(NULL, delim);
        field5 = strtok(NULL, delim);
        //field6 = strtok(NULL, delim); 
        printf("Field 1: %s\n", field1);
        printf("Field 2: %s\n", field2);
        printf("Field 3: %s\n", field3);
        printf("Field 4: %s\n", field4);
        printf("Field 5: %s\n", field5);
        //printf("Row-%d Column - %d Weight - %d\n", row, column, weight);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

On your data (stored in a file `strtok.data`), it yields:

```
The input file name is strtok.data
Input: 200 -> 103 [weight=7];
Field 1: 200
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 103
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 7
Input: 200 -> 153 [weight=27];
Field 1: 200
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 153
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 27
Input: 200 -> 53 [weight=9];
Field 1: 200
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 53
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 9
Input: 200 -> 178 [weight=43];
Field 1: 200
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 178
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 43
Input: 55 -> 2 [weight=23];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 2
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 23
Input: 55 -> 14 [weight=50];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 14
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 50
Input: 55 -> 20 [weight=17];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 20
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 17
Input: 55 -> 22 [weight=1];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 22
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 1
Input: 55 -> 74 [weight=7];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 74
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 7
Input: 55 -> 93 [weight=9];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 93
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 9
Input: 55 -> 122 [weight=27];
Field 1: 55
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 122
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 27
Input: 65 -> 8 [weight=27];
Field 1: 65
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 8
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 27
Input: 65 -> 9 [weight=9];
Field 1: 65
Field 2: ->
Field 3: 9
Field 4: weight
Field 5: 9
```

If you're getting problems, print things.  Print the input line to make sure you're reading what you think you're reading.  Print the values you do get.  If you've got a seg fault problem, be careful about printing null pointers.  Some C libraries are (far too) kind and print `<null>` or something similar if you try to print a null string; others crash.  You're lucky; you have a crashing one, so you get to know when you've got it wrong.  I didn't add code to check the returns from `strtok()`; if it was my code and I was using `strtok()` — which is not very probable; I don't like `strtok()` — then I'd be checking that each field was not null before trying again.  I'd probably be using an array and a loop instead of separately named variables, too.

Comment: Perfect.You made my life easy. :)

Comment: Thank you, but please deselect my answer and select [Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas)'a [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13664573/15168) instead.  He provided you with what should have been sufficient information. (I'm happy to keep an up-vote, but his should be the accepted answer.)

Comment: Since when is a minimal answer better than a comprehensive one? Keep the green check; you've earned it.

Answer (score 7):

You're splitting the string on spaces, so this has only 4 tokens while your code expects 6:

```
200 -> 103 [weight=7];
```

Specify `" []=;"` as delimiters to fix this. (Or include `->` as well while you're at it.)

Comment: Adding the delimiters will sort out `field5`; the only thing left for `field6` would be the newline on its own, I think.

Comment: @Thomas I still get Seg Fault.

Comment: @SOaddict: the revised code still uses blank as the `strtok()` delimiter.

Comment: @Jonathan Changed the code.